Apache Jena 4.9.0 [Endpoint returned Content-Type: application/sparql-results+json which is not recognized for SELECT queries.]
I'm developing a tool based on Apache Jena 4.9.0 libraries to issue SELECT queries to a SPARQL endpoint, and execution resulted in error stated at the title
(that is, "Endpoint returned Content-Type: application/sparql-results+json which is not recognized for SELECT queries.").
Does anyone know the reason and how to work around this?
My code is as follows and the triple stores at the endpoints are Virtuoso Open-Source Edition 7.2.13 and GraphDB 10.8.0:
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(shortTimeOut))
                    .followRedirects(Redirect.NORMAL)
                    .build();
QueryExecution gqexec = QueryExecutionHTTPBuilder
                    .service(ep)
                    .httpClient(httpClient)
                    .query(q)
                    .sendMode(QuerySendMode.asPost)
                    .timeout(longTimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
ResultSet rs = gqexec.execSelect();

And the query is
SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE { GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o} }

The followings are issued request from the tool:
Received POST request: POST /sparql HTTP/1.1

Headers:
Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
Content-Length: 48
Host: localhost:8080
HTTP2-Settings: AAEAAEAAAAIAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAQBAAAAAAUAAEAAAAYABgAA
Upgrade: h2c
User-Agent: Java-http-client/21.0.5
Accept: application/sparql-results+json, application/sparql-results+xml;q=0.9, text/tab-separated-values;q=0.7, text/csv;q=0.5,application/json;q=0.2,application/xml;q=0.2,*/*;q=0.1
Content-Type: application/sparql-query;charset=utf-8

Body:
SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE { GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o} }

Best regards.
PS. The response data are as follows:
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Virtuoso/07.20.3240 (Linux) x86_64-ubuntu_focal-linux-gnu
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2024 09:13:32 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-disposition: filename=sparql_2024-11-27_09-13-32Z.json
< Content-Type: application/sparql-results+json
< Content-Length: 12180
<
{ [12180 bytes data]

{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": ["g"] },
  "results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings": [
    { "g": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#" }},
    { "g": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#" }},
...


Is that { [12180 bytes data] really in the response? It is not legal for sparql-results+json or is that just illustration for the question?
SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE { GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o} } can be written as SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?g {}}

Could you try the current version Apache Jena 5.2.0? Do you repackage Jena jars or use Jena as a library dependency?

Thanks, and updated the libraries to Apache Jena 5.2.0, but the result hasn't been changed.
( [12180 bytes data] is not in the real response body. )

I tried ep = "https://dbpedia.org/sparql" and your example with original query and it works for me, v5.2.0. (Aside: but not SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?g {}} - different, non-Jena issue.) The ways I can get what you see is to simulate a setup where the Jena jars has been recombined in some (e.g. maven shade plugin, or an assembly combined jar)) and the service files not included.  https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html or maybe parallel thread startup (which is fixed post 5.2.0)

I'm not sure what's going on in the tool.
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.exec.http.QueryExecHTTP.raiseException(QueryExecHTTP.java:488)         at org.apache.jena.sparql.exec.http.QueryExecHTTP.execRowSet(QueryExecHTTP.java:204)         at org.apache.jena.sparql.exec.http.QueryExecHTTP.select(QueryExecHTTP.java:164)         at org.apache.jena.sparql.exec.QueryExecutionAdapter.execSelect(QueryExecutionAdapter.java:108)

That's the symptom. The cause is possibly that the result set language registry has not been initialized. Initialization happens via Java's ServiceLoader but if you are using repackages jars, the service loader configuration may have been lost by repacking. Try adding JenaSystem.DEBUG_INIT = true; JenaSystem.init(); right at the start of the tool (e.g. in main) before it calls any Jena code. The only other possibility that I can think of is parallel execution. You haven't said much about the tool.

Thanks a lot. The issue has been fixed. I use Eclipse IDE, and when exporting a runnable JAR file, it is needed to choose Package required libraries into generated JAR at the Library handling selection. I'm developing a tool to issue a series of SPARQL queries to a given endpoint to obtain statistical data, and it doesn't use parallel execution.
